# Python: Read nested data from a file into a nested dictionary without using json

Tags: python

I have a test file having data in below format, somewhat similar to json format and I want it to read it into nested dictionary without using json module.

What is the efficient way to achieve it.

```
SSS = 11111

AAA            {
                BBB           {
                                 BB_1           = First Value
                                 BB_2           = Second Value
                               }

               CCC            {
                                 CC_1            = Third Value
                                 CC_2            = [
                                                     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                                                     [9, 8, 7, 6, 4]
                                                   ]
                               }
               }

DDD = 9999

FFF            { 
                 FF_1           = Fifth Value
                 FF_2           = Sixth Value
               }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write a piece of code we call a "parser". There's plenty of resources online, just search for "how to make a parser in python" and you'll find several approaches.

Then come back to tell us how you did it.